# import fails on jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

NOTE: this is a duplicate of [import from local directory on python2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112618/import-python-package-from-local-directory-into-interpreter).

Let me say upfront, sorry as I've read thru the import rules for python, ipython and jupython and can't keep them straight anymore...

Environment:

```
ubuntu linux server with jupyterhub
jupyter home is $HOME/opt
$HOME/opt/mynotebooks                      # contains my .pynb notebooks
$HOME/opt/mynotebooks/py_lib               # contains .py files
$HOME/opt/mynotebooks/py_lib/app_config.py # myapp config/links to myapp
$HOME/opt/mynotebooks/py_lib/class1.py     # contains .py files
/opt/myapp/src/app                         # contains my app .py classes
/opt/myapp/src/app/appclass.py             # contains appclass
```

My notebook1.pynb contains the following start-up cell :

```
import os, sys
MY_NOTEBOOK = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'opt','mynotebooks')
# add my notebook to ipython path
os.chdir(MY_NOTEBOOK)
sys.path.append(MY_NOTEBOOK) 
import py_lib.app_config
print(os.getenv('MYAPP_STORE')
```

The above cell works ok.

Next, the load py_lib.class1 cell to do work...

```
from py_lib.class1 import myclass1
```

But the above gives error: "No module named class1".

If I move the app_config.py into my notebook dir it works use the following start-up cell...(NOTE import app_config changed without py_lib... I restart kernel and clear all output before re-running).   The sys.path is the same when I do the py_lib.class1 import.  Why can't it find it when app_config is 1 level down?  Makes no sense?

```
import os, sys
MY_NOTEBOOK = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME'),'opt','mynotebooks')
# add my notebook to ipython path
os.chdir(MY_NOTEBOOK)
sys.path.append(MY_NOTEBOOK) 
import app_config
print(os.getenv('MYAPP_STORE')
```

(BTW: this latter startup fails if I save notebook to py and run via python.)

$HOME/opt/mynotebooks/nb_lib/app_config.py

```
APP_SITE = os.path.join('/opt/myapp/src')
APP_STORE = os.path.join('/opt/myapp/store')
os.environ['APP_SITE'] = APP_SITE
os.environ['APP_STORE'] = APP_STORE
# Link to APP_SITE
os.chdir(APP_SITE)
sys.path.append(APP_SITE)  
APP_UPLOAD = os.path.join(APP_STORE,'upload')
```

Comment: IPython shouldn't make any difference to how imports work. Does it work if you run a regular Python script sitting in `~/opt/mynotebooks/`? Also, your description says `.../class1.py  # contains .py files` - does that mean you have a directory called `class1.py`? Or is that just copy-pasted?

Comment: Been reading... (forgot where) there seems to be a difference between IPython/python on import... at least I have observed it.  The TOP/py_lib is a packagfe (has a __init__.py) and one of the files is class1.py containing 'class myclass(object):....'

Comment: I did save the notebook as a .py file... and when I try to run the .py file with imports... the 'import app_config doesn't work.  Thus I moved it into the py_lib and 'import py_lib.app_config' works... but now the notebook didn't work???   Thus my query...

Comment: I can't work out what problem relates to what description - you appear to have tried a lot of different things, and it's not clear what order they are in or what the situation is now. I'd suggest you start with a clean directory and build the pieces up from scratch, without using `os.chdir` or `sys.path.append`, to get a simplified example of the problem. You might even find that when you do that you can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tks @Thomas... your comment inspired me to build a sample which demostrates the issue and what the objective is.   You can look in [AppNotebooks example](https://github.com/frankr6591/AppNotebooks)  if you want to see the code.   I found the issue to be py2 vs py3 handling of current directory.  Thanks again.

Comment: While I think it's generally a good idea to use Python 3, I don't think that's the real issue here. You're still using `os.chdir()` and `sys.path.append()` quite a bit, you're changing global state when modules are imported, you're hardcoding paths, you're committing the generated `.pyc` files... it's hard to know where to start unpicking it, but I think I'd say ditch the `os.chdir()` calls first. It doesn't look like there's any need for them.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue to be a duplicate of  [import from local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112618/import-python-package-from-local-directory-into-interpreter).

Specifically, "Python 2.5 for Ubuntu 8.10 does not have the current directory (empty string) in sys.path for the interpreter."

Unfortunately, my app is still on py2 so I run the notebook on py2.   I have put a sample of the [AppNotebooks](https://github.com/frankr6591/AppNotebooks).   So fix is to migrate to py3.   Or for app, put config into a sub package (ie. py_lib).