# Another "ImportError: cannot import name"

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I have four files:  `menu.py`,`notebook.py`, `__init__.py` and `test.py` which are aranged as @afaq suggested.

My `notebook.py`:

```
class Note:
    def __init__(self,memo,tag = ''):
        self.memo = memo
        self.tag = tag

    def match(self,filter):
        '''determine if this note matches the filter text, return
        true if match, false if not'''
        return filter in self.memo or filter in self.tag

class Notebook:
    def __init__(self):
        '''ininitalize a notebook with empty list'''
        self.note = []

    def search(self,filter):
        '''Find all notes that match the given filter string.'''
        return [note for note in self.note if note.match(filter)]
```

And `menu.py`: (edited)

```
import sys

from .notebook import Note, Notebook

class Menu:
    '''Display a menu and respond to choices when run.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.notebook = Notebook()
        self.choices = {
            "1": self.search_note,
            "2": self.quit
        }

    def display_menu(self):
        print("""
            Notebook Menu
            1. Search Notes
            2. Quit
            """)

    def run(self):
        '''Display the menu and respond to choices.'''
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            choice = input("Choice is: ")
            action = self.choices.get(choice)
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("{0} is not a valid choice".format(choice))

    def search_note(self):
        '''search for text and display all notes contain it'''
        filter = input("Search for: ")
        notes = self.notebook.search(filter)
        self.show_note()

    def quit(self):
        print("Bye bye")
        sys.exit(0)
```

My `__init__.py` is empty

My `test.py`:

```
from Notebook.my_notebook.menu import Menu

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Menu().run()
```

When I run `test.py`, python returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Notebook.my_notebook.menu import Menu
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Notebook'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: notebook is not global module, please read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112618/import-python-package-from-local-directory-into-interpreter

Comment: @Filip: thanks, I edit `.notebook` instead of  `notebook` and got this new error. Can you help?

Comment: Try 
`from . import notebook`

Comment: python returns me this error 
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "menu.py", line 2, in <module>
        from . import Note, Notebook
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Note'`

Comment: @SiXUlm, I have updated the executor code. Please check if it works now.

Comment: You don't have a `Notebook` package or anything named `my_notebook` or `menu`. Why were you expecting `from Notebook.my_notebook.menu import Menu` to do? How do you think import statements work?

Comment: Please don't refer to an existing question + answer without including the essentials here: make the question standalone. "arranged as @afaq suggested" doesn't mean anything (and you don't even provide a link to where that suggestion is, let alone what it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `if __name__ == "__main__":` call in a separate module. You cannot do a relative import while trying to execute that module.

Check [Ultimate answer to relative python imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299270/ultimate-answer-to-relative-python-imports)

**menu.py**

```
import sys

from .notebook import Note, Notebook

class Menu:
    '''Display a menu and respond to choices when run.'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.notebook = Notebook()
        self.choices = {
            "1": self.search_note,
            "2": self.quit
        }

    def display_menu(self):
        print("""
            Notebook Menu
            1. Search Notes
            2. Quit
            """)

    def run(self):
        '''Display the menu and respond to choices.'''
        while True:
            self.display_menu()
            choice = input("Choice is: ")
            action = self.choices.get(choice)
            if action:
                action()
            else:
                print("{0} is not a valid choice".format(choice))

    def search_note(self):
        '''search for text and display all notes contain it'''
        filter = input("Search for: ")
        notes = self.notebook.search(filter)
        self.show_note()

    def quit(self):
        print("Bye bye")
        sys.exit(0)
```

**Your directory structure should look like this.**

[image]

**Your package structure should look like this.**

[image]

**And the executor code would look like this**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I will try and be back with the results.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I'm not so clear at 3 points. First, in the first image, what is `notbook_menu`? Second, what is inside the `__init__.py`? Third, the executor code means, I will delete `if__name__ ...` line in the `menu.py`, am I right?

Comment: `notebook_menu` is just random package name that i chose for your python files.
`__init__` file is what makes your folder a python package.
And yes when you are creating an executor like i did here , you won't need `if __name__ ...` anymore in menu.py.

Comment: Sorry for the typo in `notebook_menu` in the images.

Comment: No worries about the typo. I will keep trying and let you know what I get. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested but I still got this error (please see my update). Can you help?

Comment: Do not change your existing `notebook.py` and `menu.py` code.  Moreover I don't see `from Notebook.my_notebook.menu import Menu` in your code. Why is error pointing that ?

Comment: Keep your `__init__.py` file empty.

Comment: @SiXUlm . I have updated my answer with more help. Please check.

Comment: But for me it is working fine and I can see the output as well. Not sure about your directory structure.

Comment: Thanks! Finally it works now. I really appreciate your help!