# How to use local python module>

Tags: python

I want to import a python module I have off of Github, but I want it to be portable, I.E. available to use on a memory stick, and I want to have it so I don't have to install the module through CMD on every machine I want it to run on.

I've seen [Import python package from local directory into interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112618/import-python-package-from-local-directory-into-interpreter), but none of the answers worked for me, as I don't have a specific file to target, it's a directory I want to import. The module I want to import is (https://github.com/ricmoo/pyaes)

Comment: Note that what you really want to import is the **inner** *pyaes* folder (from *GitHub*). All you have to do is add the the parent dir path (of that **inner** folder - wherever it might be) to the env var *PYTHONPATH*, start *python*, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\pyaes-master')
import pyaes
```

Comment: Which file am I using? Sorry, I'm new to this. Is it the `setup.py`?

Comment: You should use 'import pyaes' as you don't want to install it, yes?

Comment: I have downloaded the pyaes folder from Github and added it like this: `sys.path.append('C:/Users/ted67/Code/encrypt_files/pyaes')` but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: when I `import pyaes`, it says "No module named pyaes"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
from [path to directory] import [whatever you want to import]? 
That should do the trick.

Comment: Am I importing a specific file? I'm quite new to this