# How to run python without module from command line

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, command-line, python-module

I have two python files `my_python.py`

```
# my_pyhton.py
from myPython import my_utils
...
logger = my_utils.get_logger
..
```

and `my_utils.py` both in folder `myPython`:

```
# my_utils.py
def get_logger():
....
```

I can run them in eclipse PyDev without any problems, but when I run them in command line, I got error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_pyhton.py", line 19, in <module>
    from myPyhton import my_utils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myPython'
```

How can I do so that I can run them like in eclipse?

Comment: try to import like `import my_utils` in `my_python.py`.

Comment: `Unresolved import: my_utils` in my_python.py

Comment: Are you using the colon when importing?

Comment: Of course, No! just `import my_utils`

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1112618/6900838)

Comment: can you describe the directory structure?

Comment: all in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok for my case

```
from my_utils import get_logger, get_driver, get_home_path
```